# software with multiple executables management in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, client-server

I'm trying to manage a very simple client-server code using netbeans.

What is the best way to manage a project like this?

- creating 3 projects: 1 for client, 1 for server and 1 for commons?
- creating multiple jar files for each part by editing build.xml?
- creating a single jar file and run it 2 times?
- any other approach?

Comment: Do you want to create a web client or an applet or a Java app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the 3 project setup.

From what you describe it will be the most flexible setup.

You can customize the build process for each application separately, you don't need to think about which one you "just built" because it's clear.

And the "commons" project will allow you to re-use the common code very easily.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I think the best way to deal with that is to creating 2 different projects, 1 for client and 1 for server. Are you sure you need one to store commons? Usually they don't share so much methods in common.

You can also make only one project if you want to give the user the choice to act as server or client, depending on your app.